# Content Types not linked to Product Variations

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce, drupal-content-types

I am working with Commerce Kickstart 2.0.  I have created 9 content types and when I went to add the variations for each "product type" I noticed that none of them were showing up.  My content types had a large amount of fields in them so I cloned each one of them from the previous created content type, and I think this may be what caused the issue.  Is there a way for me to manually point each content type to another variation type or do I have to create all new content types from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit of a newb to Commerce kickstart but I'm pretty sure that for the built in plumbing to work as expected, you need to begin adding a new product by starting with a new product variation type (a bit counter-inuitive). This should create a product and product view automatically. You can then assign attributes common to all variations to the 'Product' and those unique to the variations to the 'Product variation'.